# Обновление entity. TransientObjectException

Tags: java, hibernate, entity, transaction

Здравствуйте имеются 3 entity (Doctor, Patient, Recipe) которые с помощью Hibernate замапленны в БД.
Recipe имеет в качестве поля Doctor и Patient.
 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При обновлении объекта (обновляются текстовые поля, не ссылки на другие сущности) Recipe загруженного в память вылетает исключение:

```
TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing
```

Обновление Recipe происходит следующим образом:

```
Recipe old_recipe = recipeService.findById(id);
old_recipe.setPriority(priority);
old_recipe.setDescription(description);
recipeService.update(old_recipe);
```

Метод update:

```
@Override
public void update(Recipe recipe) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.update(recipe);
}
```

Как правильно сделать обновление Recipe, если мне НЕ нужно пересохранять/пересоздавать имеющиеся у этого объекта внешние сущности: Doctor, Patient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решением было использовать:

```
session.refresh(recipe.getPatient());
session.refresh(recipe.getDoctor());
```

для связных сущностей объекта Recipe который обновляю.

Answer (score 0):

Исключение выдается, когда вы

хотите передать временный экземпляр методу `Session`, который ожидает постоянный экземпляр.

Перед запуском временного экземпляра убедитесь, что вы загрузили ссылки, прежде чем передавать этот временный экземпляр в метод `save`.  Если у вас нет постоянных ссылок, которые сначала сохраняют объекты, которые не имеют ссылок на другие временные экземпляры.

Comment: Перед обновлением я загружаю объект Recipe, потом меняю его поля. В данном случае этот объект временный? Но он же закеширован Hibernate?

Comment: Если у вас объект временный, то надо использовать другой метод сессии.